# Element position without top margin

Tags: jquery

If I have an element with top-margin set to some value larger than 0, and I attempt to retrieve its position will the position.top be calculated from the top-left point of the element of it's margin?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, you should provide example of what you are looking for

Comment: did you event try it? Not very difficult to test

Comment: @charlietfl Yes I did and was surprised by what I saw... Thought I'd check with the community since it was kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: well if that's the case, why didn't you post code instead of asking as if you hadn't researched anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jquery's `.position()` which will calculate the absolute position for your element without borders, margins, etc. See the [Jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/position/).

Comment: Maybe in fact OP is looking for `offset()` instead

Comment: Maybe you're saying this and I'm just confused, but the docs are saying it excludes the parent element's borders and margins. It however does include the margin and borders of the element that `.position()` is being called for. @APAD1's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

It will be from the top point of the element's margin.

```
var topPosition = $('#element').position().top;
$('#position').html('Top position: '+topPosition+'px');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L61denoe/1/)